# Animating fragment transitions

Tags: android, android-fragments

Im trying to make a fragment slide in/out on the x axis but for some reason its only animating when im entering the fragment. When going backwards it doesnt animate at all.

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_right);
EditFragment edit = EditFragment.newInstance();
transaction.replace(android.R.id.content, edit, "editFragment");
transaction.addToBackStack("editFragment");
transaction.commit();
```

Is it maybe because im exiting the fragment this way?

```
getActivity().onBackPressed();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the [`setCustomAnimations`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentTransaction#setCustomAnimations(int,int,int,int)) method with four arguments:

```
public @NonNull FragmentTransaction setCustomAnimations(
    @AnimatorRes @AnimRes int enter,
    @AnimatorRes @AnimRes int exit,
    @AnimatorRes @AnimRes int popEnter,
    @AnimatorRes @AnimRes int popExit
)
```

Comment: guess thats what ive been missing